# Barycentric subdivision in convex sets: is Rotman's definition incorrect?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, barycentric-coordinates

In Rotman's *An Introduction to Algebraic Topology*, 4th printing, pp. 113, he provided a definition of barycentric subdivision in a convex set $E$:

> Let $E$ be a convex set. Then **barycentric subdivision** is a homomorphism $\operatorname{Sd}_n:S_n(E)\to S_n(E)$ defined inductively on generators $\tau:\Delta^n\to E$ as follows:
>
> (i) If $n=0$, then $\operatorname{Sd}_0(\tau)=\tau$;
> (ii) If $n>0$, then $\operatorname{Sd}_n(\tau)=\tau(b_n).\operatorname{Sd}_{n-1}(\partial\tau)$, where $b_n$ is the barycenter of $\Delta^n$.

Here $b.\sigma$ is the cone construction. This definition does *not* really affect the subsequent arguments: the barycentric subdivision in a general space $X$ is immediately defined as

> $$\operatorname{Sd}_n(\sigma)=\sigma_\sharp\operatorname{Sd}_n(\delta^n)$$ (here $\sigma:\Delta^n\to X$ is a $n$-simplex and $\delta^n$ is the identity map of $\Delta^n$).

Thus we only need the definition of $\operatorname{Sd}_n(\delta^n)$ to be correct, which is nevertheless the case. However, the aforementioned definition in convex sets does not make sense to me and seems wrong in its own regard, as Rotman mentioned

> It is easy to see that both definitions of $\operatorname{Sd}_n(\sigma)$ agree when $X$ is convex.

This is obviously not true. Consider the unit circle on complex plane $\sigma:I\to\mathbb C$, $t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$. By the definition in convex sets, the barycentric subdivision of $\sigma$ (viewed as a $1$-cycle) is $0$, while by the definition in general spaces it is a non-zero linear combination of two semicircles.

In fact, in other sources the barycentric subdivision in convex/affine set is only defined on the free abelian group generated by affine simplicies, i.e. the linear chain $LC_n(E)$ (the notation in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*). In this case, all arguments run smoothly and the definition coincides with that for general $X$.

So is this a typo in the book? Is Rotman's definition incorrect?

Comment: The unit circle is not a convex subset of the plane.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip From what I cite, it seems the definition only requires the underlying space (in this case, the complex plane) to be convex.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip And even if we ask the image of $\sigma$ to be convex, it still appears incorrect. One may replace the circle example by a path going straight from $a$ to $b$ and then coming back.

Comment: okay, I see what you mean. I read your post too quickly. I think it's probably a mistake in Rotman's book.